# How can I export the data in a DataGridView data to an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: winforms, excel, datagridview

In my Winforms application, I want to export the data from my DataGridView to a Excel spreadsheet.

Is it simply a job of looping and outputting the results comma seperated?

Comment: For sample C# code to export CSV, check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343420/how-to-export-datagridview-data-to-excel/12023098#12023098

Answer (score 1):

*Is it simply a job of looping and outputing the results comma seperated?* Yes. It is a simpler way without any dependencies.

If you need more control, you can always automate excel from [vb.net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982) or from [C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)..

Answer (score 1):

Outputting results comma separated will give you a .csv not an excel spreadsheet; although excel can read a csv, and once open in excel you could save it document as excel file. To actually write a file in the excel format I believe you have to use an Ole Provider or something like that, but I've never bothered, since the workaround of creating a csv and outside of code making it an excel file is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly hacky, but Excel will also open a html file saved with a .xls extension. This has the advantage of being able to include formatting.