# Export DataTable to Excel Sheet - Getting Empty Rows When Creating

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, dataset

I have a dataset that consists of 6 tables. When I place them into my method below, it works flawlessly on the first table. However, I notice in the second table the second row (under the columns) is blank and then the table data is shown. This is the same for table three only this time there are two rows which are blank. This increases the blank row as each remaining table is built. I verified that the tables themselves do not have these empty rows. I am hoping that someone here would be so kind to look at this code and let me know what would be the cause of this.

```
public Excel.Application PrepareForExport(System.Data.DataSet ds)
{
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(missing);
    int k = 0;
    int tableCount = 6;
    for (int j = 0; j < tableCount; j++)  
    {
        Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
        newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excel.Worksheets.Add(missing, missing, missing, missing);


        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[j];
        // name sheet
        string tableName = string.Empty;

        switch (j)
        {
            case 0: 
                tableName = "TEST1";
                break;
            case 1:
                tableName = "TEST2";
                break;
            case 2:
                tableName = "TEST3";
                break;
            case 3:
                tableName = "TEST4";
                break;
            case 4:
                tableName = "TEST5";
                break;
            case 5:
                tableName = "TEST6";
                break;
            default:
                tableName = "INVALID";
                break;
        }

        newWorksheet.Name = tableName;


        int iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            iCol++;
            excel.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;
        }


        int iRow = 0 + k;
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            iRow++;


            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                if (iRow == 1)
                {
                    // Add the header the first time through 
                    excel.Cells[iRow, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                }

                if (r[1].ToString() != "")
                {
                    excel.Cells[iRow + 1, i] = r[i - 1].ToString() + " - " + dt.Columns.Count;
                }
            }

        }
        k++;
    }
    return excel;
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Another approach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343420/how-to-export-datagridview-data-to-excel/9343484#9343484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your int k variable and iRow that are the problems.
You set

```
int k = 0;
```

outside your looping through the tables.
Then inside the loop you have

```
int iRow = 0 + k;
```

and then you increment k at the end of the loop.
So for the first table you've got iRow = 0; second table, iRow = 1; third table, iRow = 2.